# Form not working with more than 10 choices using CommaSeparatedIntegerField in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

After following the rather useful blog [post](http://eudaimonia.io/django/multi-select-list-in-django.html), I am having issues with the widget (forms.SelectMultiple or forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) not correctly showing which choices have previously been selected, if the number of choices is > 9.

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Flower(models.Model):
  '''Flowers'''

  flowers = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=100, default="1,2", blank=True)
```

Form:

```
from django import forms

class FlowerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    FLOWERS = (
    ('0', 'Daisies'),
    ('1', 'Petunias'),
    ('2', 'Roses'),
    ('3', 'Forget-me-nots'),
    ('4', 'Choice 4'),
    ('5', 'Choice 5'),
    ('6', 'Choice 6'),
    ('7', 'Choice 7'),
    ('8', 'Choice 8'),
    ('9', 'Choice 9'),
    ('10', 'Choice 10'),
    ('11', 'Choice 11'),
    ('12', 'Choice 12'),
    ('13', 'Choice 13'),
    )

  flowers = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FLOWERS, initial="1")


  def clean_flowers(self):
      field = ""
      for data in self.cleaned_data['flowers']:
        field += str(data)+","
      return field.lstrip(",")
```

If you select any choices in the list, it does correctly save to the database (via the cleaning function), but when you go back to the form choices above 9 are no longer selected. Other choices are marked as selected instead - choice 1 and the value-10; e.g. if you choose choice 13, choices 1 & 3 will be selected when going back to the form

Please help!?!

Edit: FYI, I'm using Django 1.8.3 with Python 3.4.0.

Comment: doesn't fix your problem, but you could make the `clean_flowers` method simpler by just doing `return ",".join(self.cleaned_data['flowers'])` ...handy python pattern to learn :)

Comment: another problem is you are breaking the contract of a Django `clean_<field>` method, which should return the (modified) `cleaned_data` dict https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: Not sure about that - even the example in the 1.8 docs you link to just returns the field data, not the dict?  It mentions in the section below if you are cleaning the entire form data it should return the dict, but even that is optional from Django>=1.7.  And besides, its doesn't fix the issue anyway.

Comment: my mistake, sorry, you are correct my secong comment above is just wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to the link from Anentropic, one of the comments on the linked page was for someone who has expanded that snippet into django-multiselectfield:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/0.1.3

I've installed that, changed my model to use that new MultiSelectField fieldtype, and it all works.  Many thanks to Anentropic for getting me there.

Shame about the poorly documented CommaSeparatedIntegerField fieldtype though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you convert the list to a comma separated string in your clean method... it looks like this value is then used by Django when displaying the form.

It seems Django is expecting a list and iterating over the field value, so when you pass it say `'13'` Django will select `'1'` and `'3'` (because strings are iterable as lists of characters)

So there's a problem matching what the form expects (list of values) with what the db field expects (comma separated string)

I don't think there is a straightforward solution.

Maybe try something like this snippet with custom db field as a starting point:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2753/

Comment: Thats great, thanks.  I tried to upvote but I don't have any reputation here :(